# CSS Image on background and texte

Tags: html, css, web, responsive

First sorry for bad english, not my native language.
I try multiple way, but nothing that works.

```
I want to transforme my list (which are actualy boostrap alert) -> before
```

[image]

```
into list with an image and center text like this -> after
```

[image]
I try with background-image CSS property, but I can't manipulate size of the image used. I try also img and text on a div in HTML, but doesn't work eather.
And that need to be responsive ^^

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Please post your code. make a working snippet.

Comment: Do you use a list or a table or another html structure?

Comment: Please embed the images in your question for the case when the external service is unavailable.

Answer (score -1):

You can `manipulate size of the image used` e.g. with `background-size: cover;`
Just put if after setting `background` property. Google in this direction, this property has other helpful values.